# Very Slow Reverse Proxy on Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

This is on a server running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, serving an Angular web application. The sites works completely fine, but is very slow to load pages, taking a number of minutes at times. I've tried various solution including [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/796735/nginx-reverse-proxy-is-slow). Which did significantly speed up the site but made some pages inaccessible. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;

   listen 443 ssl; 
   ssl_certificate /location/ 
   ssl_certificate_key /location/

    root /location/;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name site.net;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=500;

location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
            proxy_buffering off;
           }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A well performing web server often is the result of many small optimizations. But page loads taking multiple minutes(!) looks more like a misconfiguration than missing performance optimizations.

As you did not tell exactly what parts of your page loads are slow … this is what I would do:

1. Check for slow network connection on client: https://fast.com

   - Is it really the server? Or is it your connection to the server?
2. Check for page loading times on https://www.webpagetest.org

   - TTFB slow? -> Check DNS. Check SSL negotiation. Check caches on server.
   - Completing the initial request takes long? -> Check for slow database queries. Check for missing database table indexes. Check application code.
   - Check for initial redirects often making slow sites even slower. -> Check for consistent usage of trailing slashes in nginx config and application code.
3. Check nginx vhost config.

   - Placing both listening on :80 and :443 in one `server` block seems no ok. You would like to redirect :80 requests to :443 for sure, so you should split :80 and :443 into two 'server' blocks.
   - Server not listening to IPv6 on :443 seems not ok.
   - Maybe add http2 support 443 listen parameter
4. Check nginx log files.

   - Maybe use advanced logging features and add timing information to log_format. See [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-logging-for-application-performance-monitoring/).
   - Turn off logging in production if not needed.
5. Check nginx.conf.

   - Values for worker_processes and worker_connections ok?
   - Rate limiting active?
6. Check for performance difference when serving the application directly instead of through proxy_pass.
7. Check caching on server.
8. Check more for more performance tuning options with nginx [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/10-tips-for-10x-application-performance/).
9. Check Ubuntu logs eg. syslog for other issues like failing hard drives, fail2ban problem …
10. Good luck!