# NGINX is giving 404 errors on all but the HTML pages

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, docker

I setup nginx as a reverse proxy in a docker container to link to sites outside of the container.  I have a vhost config setup as follows (I tried adding the ^~ before the location for home-assistant):

```
server { # simple reverse-proxy
    listen       80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.99:6789;
    }

    location ^~ /home-assistant {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.99:8123/;
    }

    location /calibre-web/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.99:8181/;
    }

  }
```

For both home-assistant and calibre-web sites, the page loads, but I get 404 errors for all other items (images, CSS, etc...).  **If I try to click a link in the applications, it links me to 192.168.1.99/file and not 192.168.1.99/site-folder/file as it should**.  Below are a few records from the logs (note the one 200 response, and the other 404 responses).  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
192.168.1.6 - randy [15/Aug/2016:03:15:42 +0000] "GET /frontend/panels/dev-template-0a099d4589636ed3038a3e9f020468a7.html HTTP/1.1" 404 199 "http://192.168.1.99/home-assistant/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8350.60.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.85 Safari/537.36"

192.168.1.6 - randy [15/Aug/2016:03:15:42 +0000] "GET /frontend/panels/logbook-66108d82763359a218c9695f0553de40.html HTTP/1.1" 404 199 "http://192.168.1.99/home-assistant/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8350.60.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.85 Safari/537.36"

192.168.1.6 - randy [15/Aug/2016:03:17:54 +0000] "GET /home-assistant/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1654 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8350.60.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.85 Safari/537.36"

192.168.1.6 - randy [15/Aug/2016:03:17:55 +0000] "GET /static/icons/favicon-192x192.png HTTP/1.1" 404 91 "http://192.168.1.99/home-assistant/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8350.60.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.85 Safari/537.36"

192.168.1.6 - randy [15/Aug/2016:03:17:55 +0000] "GET /static/core-457d5acd123e7dc38947c07984b3a5e8.js HTTP/1.1" 404 91 "http://192.168.1.99/home-assistant/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8350.60.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.85 Safari/537.36"
```

[Here is a copy of my root nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/abb2c89879d41074ad1c48aec4a7a48b).  I'm guessing the error is in here somewhere, I just cant figure out where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to proxy_pass requests from a location that is unknown to the original application. In docker container application still believes that it is accessed from the website root (`http://192.168.1.99:8123/`), so it generates all URLs relative to `/`, not to your `/home-assistant/` or `/calibre-web/`.

There are numerous ways to solve this problem, you should choose whatever works best for you:

#### 1. Replacing links in proxied html

First of all it is replacing every link received from the proxied application before submitting result to the client is possible with [ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html). It's not enabled by default, so you may have to [compile nginx from source](https://serverfault.com/questions/795556/supporting-http2-on-amazon-linux-with-apache-with-openssl-1-0-1/795582#795582) if your distro doesn't have it (to check availability of this module run `nginx -V`, which should display `--with-http_sub_module` somewhere along configuration parameters).

If you choose this method, add the following directives to your config:

```
location ^~ /home-assistant {
    rewrite ^/home-assistant(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.99:8123/;
    sub_filter "<head>" "<head><base href=\"${scheme}://${host}/home-assistant\">";
}
```

#### 2. Changing application path inside the container

Moving application inside docker container to the `/home-assistant` instead of root, so it would generate all URLs in served content related to that path instead of root `/`. This is an obvious (and probably the easiest) solution, which doesn't require touching nginx configs at all (instead you edit configuration inside docker)

#### 3. Choosing upstream based on the Referer header

Determining which upstream should be used based on the `Referer` header. [Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242357/proxying-relative-urls-with-nginx). Seems pretty smart, though I wouldn't use it in production myself (note it only works for css/js files).

```
location ~* ^/(css|js)/.+\.(css|js)$ {
    #checking if referer is from home-assistant
    if ($http_referer ~ "^.*/home-assistant"){
        return 417;
    }

    #checking if referer is from calibre-web
    if ($http_referer ~ "^.*/calibre-web"){
        return 418;
    }
}

error_page   417  /home-assistant$request_uri;
error_page   418  /calibre-web$request_uri;

location ^~ /home-assistant {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.99:8123/;
}

location /calibre-web {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.99:8181/;
}
```

If I were you, I'd go with #2 - moving apps inside the container as the easiest & the least error-prone way to get what you need.

P.S. I completely forgot that you can serve static files directly from your hard drive, since your backend is on the same server as nginx. It will require some application-dependant configuration, but as a result you'll get most efficient solution..

Comment: Thanks so much for the thoughtful answer!  I was wondering if that was the case, I just don't have enough expertise to know.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on why the third option might not be stable ("I wouldn't use it in production") and why it only works for css/js? I am thinking about putting a bunch of Dashboard apps (RShiny/Python Dash) behind a reverse proxy and the second option only seems to work with Dash (passing the `url_base_pathname` option). And since I intended to just use an existing nginx image, the first option does not seem very enticing. Plus it basically seems to be a search&replace on files which... probably has weird edge cases which will probably go wrong eventually

Comment: @FelixB. "in production" i'd just use subdomains or even better fix the app behind proxy so it would give correct urls as it is

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be not to pass an URI in the `proxy_pass` directive:

```
location ^~ /home-assistant {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.99:8123;
}

location ^~ /calibre-web/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.99:8181;
}
```

Notice the missing `/` character after port number in `proxy_pass` statement. That means that nginx will pass the URI sent to the server to the app server.

With the `/` character (URI), it will replace the request URI with that.

This behavior is documented at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass